# how can I reverse my array using only one Array instead of using two?

Tags: javascript, arrays, stack, reverse

I am fairly new to JavaScript and programming in general.
I was experimenting with some code to reverse an array with push and Pop. I know I can use Array.prototype.reverse() but I wanted to experiment and play around.

here are my questions

- 1) why do I get undefined in the last line of code? since I returned
  the array?
- 2) why `ReverseStack(stack,reversed.push(stack.pop()))`
  not a function error?
- 3) how can I get the same result but without
  using a second array? using only push & pop

```js
const stack = [];
const reversed = [];
stack.push("a");
stack.push("b");
stack.push("c");
stack.push("d");
stack.push("e");
stack.push("f");

ReverseStack = (stack, reversed) =>{

    for(let i = 0; i <= stack.length; i++) {
        if (stack.length === 0){
            console.log(reversed); //output [ 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' ]
            return reversed
        }
        else{
            reversed.push(stack.pop()); //store popped item in poppedItems
            ReverseStack(stack,reversed)

            //why the below does not work? it says reversed.push is not a function
            //ReverseStack(stack,reversed.push(stack.pop()))
        }
    }
};

console.log(ReverseStack(stack, reversed)); //output undefined ? why is that
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

#### Idea:

- Remove first item and save it.
- Repeat the process for remaining items till length is 1.
- Push stored values in returned array.

Note:

- `Array.pop` is different from `Stack.pop`. `Array.pop` removes last element and `Stack.pop` removes first. You can use `Array.shift` for this.

Following is a sample:

```js
const stack = [];
stack.push("a");
stack.push("b");
stack.push("c");
stack.push("d");
stack.push("e");
stack.push("f");

ReverseStack = (stack) => {
  if (stack.length > 1) {
    const head = stack.shift();
    const reverse = ReverseStack(stack);
    reverse.push(head)
    return reverse;
  }
  return stack;
};

console.log(ReverseStack(stack.slice()));
```

Comment: This creates a bunch of intermediate arrays though. But I'm not sure a general solution is possible unless one creates at least one intermediate array *or* uses something other than `push` / `pop`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, it creates intermediate arrays but I have faced lot of issues due to reference and hence prefers to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Because the return statement is within the `if` block and not outside of the `if-else` block.  therefore, the function `ReverseStack` at the end is returning an implicit `undefined` value.

I think you don't need to log/return the result of the function `ReverseStack` because you're modifying the array `reversed` in memory.

```js
const stack = [];
const reversed = [];
stack.push("a");
stack.push("b");
stack.push("c");
stack.push("d");
stack.push("e");
stack.push("f");

let ReverseStack = (stack, reversed) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= stack.length; i++) {
    if (stack.length !== 0) {
      reversed.push(stack.pop());
      ReverseStack(stack, reversed);
    }
  }
};

ReverseStack(stack, reversed);
console.log(reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) why do I get undefined in the last line of code? since I returned the array?

Your function is recursive. Although you return the `reversed` on the final condition, you're not returning anything when the `else` statement is entered. You need to return the recursive call in the `else` for the return value to percolate up back to the outer caller of `ReverseStack`:

```js
const stack = [];
const reversed = [];
stack.push("a");
stack.push("b");
stack.push("c");
stack.push("d");
stack.push("e");
stack.push("f");

ReverseStack = (stack, reversed) =>{

    for(let i = 0; i <= stack.length; i++) {
        if (stack.length === 0){
            console.log(reversed); //output [ 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' ]
            return reversed
        }
        else{
            reversed.push(stack.pop()); //store popped item in poppedItems
            return ReverseStack(stack,reversed)

            //why the below does not work? it says reversed.push is not a function
            //ReverseStack(stack,reversed.push(stack.pop()))
        }
    }
};

console.log(ReverseStack(stack, reversed)); //output undefined ? why is that
```

> 2) why ReverseStack(stack,reversed.push(stack.pop())) not a function error?

Because `.push` returns the new length of the array, not the mutated array, so the recursive call of

```
ReverseStack(stack,reversed.push(stack.pop()))
```

is calling `ReverseStack` with two arguments: an array, and an integer. But the function expects the second argument to be an array.

> 3) how can I get the same result but without using a second array? using only push & pop

Not using another array or data structure *and* only using `push` and `pop` might be difficult, maybe impossible (feel free to prove me wrong, but I can't think of a way). A different approach, using indicies, is to iterate from the middle: - switch around, eg, indicies 2 and 3, then 1 and 4, then 0 and 5, without recursion:

```js
const stack = [];
stack.push("a");
stack.push("b");
stack.push("c");
stack.push("d");
stack.push("e");
stack.push("f");

ReverseStack = (stack) => {
  for (let i = Math.ceil((stack.length - 1) / 2); i < stack.length; i++) {
    [stack[i], stack[stack.length - i - 1]] = [stack[stack.length - i - 1], stack[i]]
  }
  return stack;
};

console.log(ReverseStack(stack));
```

Comment: FYI *reverse an array with push and Pop*